# HTML5 input date to T-Sql date with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, azure, date

I am trying to convert a date from my HTML 5 form:

```
<form ng-submit="Add()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Data.title" />
  <input type="date" ng-model="Data.date"/>
</form>
```

my Azure T-Sql datebase - date - expects the following:

```
2018-01-23T18:18:43.768Z
```

but it gets from the form:

```
Wed Jan 17 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

how do i convert the html5 input date in angular to the right format so my form is submitted

```
    $scope.Add = function () {

        var request = 'additem';

        var Date = $scope.Data.date;

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: uri + request,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: 
            $.param({
                title: $scope.Data.title,
                date: $scope.Data.date

            })
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        })
    };
```

how should i convert the date so the database excepts the form, if i change the date section to just the string it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function formatDate(d) {

   return new Date(
      Date.UTC(
        d.getFullYear(),
        d.getMonth(),
        d.getDate(),
        d.getHours(),
        d.getMinutes(),
        d.getSeconds()
     )
   ).toISOString();
}
```

But you may need to be aware of inconsistencies if the local time differs a lot from UTC. You might find that a date can show as the previous day.

If you don't mind using a library for a minor task you can check on Moment.js as well. It does a lot of date conversions very easily.